# AngularJs Form based directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How to create an angularjs directive with input text for phone number and button to click based in this javascript code:

```
    function Click2Call($element) {
      $element.on("click", function () {
        let num = $element.nextAll('input').val();
        if (!isStringEmpty(num)) {
            let act= save(num);
            OpenBa(num, act);
        }
      });
    }

    function OpenB(a, b){
       //some instuct
    }

    function save(a){
      // some instruct
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question correctly, but there are some basic templates on Angularjs documentations for form. You can check them under this link,
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms
I hope it helps you

Comment: I have an input which contain the phone number <input type="text" id="phone" /> and I want to create a directive button when I click on it, it call the function Click2Call